# loop troubles with minkowski distance forumla

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

The code I have written for a Minkowski distance will not store any values. What am I doing wrong/missing? Users is a dictionary object and Veronica is just a member in the dictionary.

```
##not working,not storing values always returns -1             
def minkowski(r,rating1,rating2):
    distance = 0
    commonRatings = False 
    for band in rating1:
        if band in rating2:
            distance += abs((rating1[band]-rating2[band])* r) * 1/r
            commonRatings = True 
        if commonRatings:  
            return distance
        else:
            return -1        
print(minkowski(2,"Veronica",users))
```

this function works just fine. There is a problem with r. For whatever reason, the function will only return -1 when r is involved. Even when the r values is changed to the squared version, -1 is all that is returned

```
#manhattan function
def sum_manhattan(rating1,rating2):
    total = 0
    commonRatings = False 
    for band in rating1:
        if band in rating2:
            total += abs(rating1[band]-rating2[band])
            commonRatings = True
    if commonRatings:  
        return total
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: What does "users" look like.  It would appear that "if band in rating2" is always false.

Comment: `for band in rating1:` iterates through each letter of `rating1` which, in this case, is `'Veronica'`. I doubt thats what you want?

Comment: users is a large dictionary with many small dictionaries in it. There is the main dictionary of all the users names. Within each user name is another dictionary containing the bands that they have rated.

Comment: Then it would be useful if your example passed in two sample dictionaries. Anyway, the problem is with indentation

Comment: Another issue..."if band in rating2:" is not going to recursively check all the subdictionaries for a particular string.  If you have a nested structure, you have to apply the logic at the appropriate level.  Again, even a small sample input would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems in your function.

Mainly, the indentation of the final `if` statement is suspect. As written, this loop is guaranteed to exit on the very first pass of the loop:

```
for band in rating1:
    if band in rating2:
        distance += abs((rating1[band]-rating2[band])* r) * 1/r
        commonRatings = True 
    if commonRatings:  
        return distance
    else:
        return -1
```

After evaluating the initial `if` statement, `commonRatings` is either `True`, or `False`. Then the second `if` statement is inside the loop, and both branches contain a `return` statement.

So, you will never make it to the second pass of the loop.

rewrite the function as

```
def minkowski(r,rating1,rating2):
    distance = 0
    commonRatings = False 
    for band in rating1:
        if band in rating2:
            distance += abs((rating1[band]-rating2[band])* r) * 1/r
            commonRatings = True 

    if commonRatings:  
        return distance
    else:
        return -1
```

and you should get very different results.

Next, what is the value of `rating[band] - rating2[band]`, when both arguments are strings?

Finally, the calculation of distance is

```
abs((a - b) * r) / r
```

What is the point of multiplying and then dividing by `r` unless it is to apply the sign of `r` to the result?

To test the modified code, I defined as shown (with the modified indentation) then invoked it thus:

```
In [4]: minkowski(2,{"A" : 1 }, {"B": 2, "A": 4})
Out[4]: 3
```

Update:

The mystery of `r` is resolved. According to Wikipedia, you need to be doing:

```
distance += abs(rating1[band] - rating2[band]) ** r
```

then returning

```
distance ** (1.0/r)
```

I.e you need exponentiation not multiplication in the loop, and then return the `r`th root.

Final Update:

With the function defined thus:

```
def minkowski(r,rating1,rating2):
    distance = 0
    commonRatings = False 
    for band in rating1:
        if band in rating2:
            distance += abs(rating1[band]-rating2[band]) ** r 
            commonRatings = True 

    if commonRatings:  
        return distance ** (1.0/r)
    else:
        return -1
```

I get the following in Python 3.4

```
In [1]: minkowski(2,{"A" : 1 }, {"B": 2, "A": 4})
Out[1]: 3.0

In [2]: minkowski(2,{"A" : 1, "B": 4 }, {"B": 2, "A": 4})
Out[2]: 3.605551275463989

In [3]: minkowski(4,{"A" : 1, "B": 4 }, {"B": 2, "A": 4})
Out[3]: 3.138288992714996

In [4]: minkowski(1,{"A" : 1, "B": 4 }, {"B": 2, "A": 4})
Out[4]: 5.0
```

Comment: the function still returns -1

Comment: rating[band] are not strings. The bands are strings sure but they contain ratings which are numerical values. The code works perfectly fine if there is no r -value assigned. If we take out r in the function parameter, and just have rating 1 and rating 2 and just take the abs value then we get all the distances. The code works in that respect, it's not totally horrendous. However, when I add the parameter r and the r value to the funciton, all of a sudden it will only return -1.

Comment: Are you calling it with sensible data now? It expects two `dict`s. What are you passing in?

Comment: I'm passing in two dictionaries, as far as I understand, yes

Comment: Works for me .. see my latest edit. Which python version are you using?

Comment: 3.43. I don't know, still returns -1. Thanks for your help, but I am so bummed. I'll probably spend 3-4 hours trying to figure this out, as per the norm.

Comment: Ahhh , python 3 has some vagaries. Let me check

Comment: honestly I must not be passing in dictionaries. however I don't get how that is possible. Again when r was gone, no problems. Got the values everything worked as it should. What changed? I don't understand